# Tcp Client getting disconnected after port is getting changed

Tags: c++

I am a newbie for TCP implementation. The implementation is there in a way where the system is sending log messages to the `syslog` server for any events happening in the system using TCP using port 601.

Problem is when I am changing the port to some other (say, 662) the messages are stopped being sent. So again when i am changing the port back to 601, the messages are still not sent to the `syslog` server.
What can be the reason?

Code Snippet Below:

```
int Demo::LogMessageToRemoteSyslog(int pri, char *facility, char *buf)
{
    if ((n = ACE_OS::send(m_Handle, tbuf, cnt, 0)) != cnt)
    {
        SYSLOGTRACE(SDI_LEVEL_ERROR,"SENDING TO REMOTE SYSLOG FAILED");
        return -1;
    }
    return RetVal;
}
```

`m_Handle` is defined in constructor of `Demo` as  `m_Handle = ACE_INVALID_HANDLE;`

When the messages are not being sent,its returning `-1` from `send()`.
How can I again connect to that old port and establish the connection?
Please help me in this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The port is a part of the socket_address. Both communication partners must share the a knowledge about a an socket_address. If you change the address at one the the other doesn't know about it. If you did something else, ask more precisely. Did you change the port at the side the calls `connnect`? Did you also change anything else?

Comment: Why are you fiddling around with the port number, and why are you surprised that it breaks connections?